# Django-haystack form validation

Tags: django, django-forms, django-haystack

I have a search view on my application build on django-haystack. It works fine.

```
from haystack.forms import SearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import SearchView

class SearchView(SearchView):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(lang=get_language())
    template = "search/search.html"
    searchqueryset = sqs
    results_per_page=10
    form_class=SearchForm
```

I want to add a custom validation to this view to set minimum input value. What is the most appropriate way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation is a part of form behavior, so you need to create successor of SearchForm and add custom validation there. There is [example](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html#creating-your-own-form) in docs.